# Signing with XAdeS-BES in Android

Tags: java, android, xades4j, type-signature

I am trying to sign a file with XADES-BES in Android. I have found a library about that. Building and creating APK works fine. After I choose the file and click on the Sign button, it gives an runtime error. After debugging I found that there is a mistake about **Context**. I added a comment where the program crashes. The related part of the code is below:

```
 String sourceFilePath = filePathView.getText().toString();
                if(sourceFilePath.isEmpty()){
                    exc = new Exception("No File Picked");
                    return null;
                }
                mAPDUSmartCard.login(pwdText);
                Pair<CardTerminal,ECertificate> selection = certListAdapter.getSelection();
                ECertificate signCert = selection.second;
                BaseSigner signer = mAPDUSmartCard.getSigner(signCert.asX509Certificate(), Algorithms.SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);
                Context context = new Context();
                XMLSignature signature = new XMLSignature(context); // THIS IS WHERE THE APP CRASHES.
                signature.addDocument(sourceFilePath,"application/xml", false);        
                signature.getSignedInfo().setSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA256);
                signature.addKeyInfo(signCert);
                signature.sign(signer);
                signature.write(new FileOutputStream(sourceFilePath + ".xsig"));
```

I did not use Xades4j lib, because I don't know how to convert this code in a suitable form for cades4j lib.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about the library you're using, but regarding xades4j, you can follow documentation on the [project wiki](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki/SignatureProduction). From your code, it seems like a simple scenario that should be supported by xades4j.

Comment: Okay, I will read the documentation carefully and try to convert my code to xades4j. Thanks.